# PHP fat free framework using $this when not in object context?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo, fat-free-framework

I am developing a project using [fat free PHP framework](http://fatfreeframework.com/home). In the documentation, they said you can build your own skeleton for the project, so my project directory is like the following:

- assets

  - css
  - js
- controllers

  - Controller.php
  - Home_Controller.php
- lib (which has the framework stuff)
- models

  - Model.php
  - Model_Home.php
- views

  - home

    - main.html
- index.php

in the index.php I am calling the framework (controllers and models including the database connection) and having my routes as the following:

```
// Kickstart the framework
$f3=require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/project_name/lib/base.php');
$f3->set('AUTOLOAD',''.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/project_name/controllers/; '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/project_name/models/');

$f3->set('DEBUG',3);
if ((float)PCRE_VERSION<7.9){
    trigger_error('PCRE version is out of date');
}

if (!($f3->get('DEBUG')))
{
    $f3->set('ONERROR',
        function($f3) {
                $f3->reroute('/');
        }
    );
}

/****************** Start Routing the URLs ******************/

/****** Home Controller ******/
$f3->route('GET|HEAD /',
    function($f3) {
        $f3->reroute('/home');
    }
);

$f3->route('GET|HEAD /index',
    function($f3) {
        $f3->reroute('/home');
    }
);

$f3->route('GET /home','Controller_Home->main');

$f3->run();
```

inside Model.php I have a function that connect successfully to the database that I have like the following:

```
class Model
{
    public $f3, $db;

    public function connect()
    {   
        global $db;

        $username = 'username';
        $password = 'password';
        $hostname = 'hostname';
        $dbname = 'dbname';

        try{
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        print_r($db); // this will give PDO Object ( )
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
// if you try to execute query here, it will work.
```

Now, in Controller.php I am calling the connect() function in Model.php inside the construct like the following:

```
class Controller extends Model
{
    public $f3, $db;

    public function __construct($f3)
    {
        $this->f3 = $f3;
        $this->connect();
    }   
}
```

Model_Home.php has functions that queries the database like the following:

```
class Model_Home extends Model
{
    public $f3, $db;

    public static function getUsers()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        $output = '';
        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $output.= '<tr>
                            <td>'.$row['attrib1'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['attrib2'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['attrib3'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['attrib4'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['attrib5'].'</td>
                      </tr>';
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```

and Controller_Home.php will call the previous function statically and then call the right view to render the result like the following:

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller
{
    public $f3, $db;

    public function main($output = '')
    {
        //setting up the variables
        $this->f3->set('getUsersTable', Model_Home::getUsers());
       // getUsersTable is a variable that will be passed to the view to reder

        //calling the view
        $this->f3->set('main','views/home/main.html');
    }
}
```

The last thing is the main.html page which is like the following:

```
<h1>All Users</h1></br>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($getUsersTable); ?>
```

when I run the code, it will give me an error message says: 
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

project_name/models/Model_Home.php:8

which refers to the following line in Model_Home.php

```
$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

the php version that I have to use is 5.4 (pretty old). Any idea, please!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: The nice thing about a "Fat Free" framework is that it allows you to do things your way, without imposing rigid rules. I would recommend taking out database access credentials out of your model, and use a config(.ini) file to store these. Also, instead of having the model have a connect function called every time you call its constructor, you should only connect once and reuse the same connection. If you're interested in more detail, you can have a look at this project https://github.com/Alanaktion/phproject which I believe has a very nice setup

Comment: You are absolutely right, I tried to establish the connection one time in the constructor in my code but it did not work. Right now, each time I am I wanna execute a query, I am calling the connect function. Could you please help me out figuring this using my skeleton. Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined Model_Home::getUsers as a static method.  This means it is a method of the class and not the instantiated object, which in turn means you don't get access to object properties, only class properties and methods defined as "static" .  $db is not defined as "static" and therefore it's a property of the object and not the class.

**If you want to keep getUsers as static:**

You can either define $db as "static" (which will require other code changes for any code that references it), or use the Singleton pattern whereby an instance of an object is stored as a static class variable for access by other class methods.  Eg:

```
class myClass
{
    protected static $db = null;

    public static function getDb()
    {
        if(empty(self::$db))
            self::$db = new Database();

        return self::$db;
    }
}
```

**If you don't care about keeping getUsers static:**

Just remove the "static" keyword from its declaration, and you will also have to update this method call from:

```
$this->f3->set('getUsersTable', Model_Home::getUsers());
```

to:

```
$modelHome = new Model_Home;
$this->f3->set('getUsersTable', $modelHome->getUsers());
```

Comment: Ok, so what you're saying is to make a function that calls the DB statically and put that function inside the Model.php

Comment: Or the second option I just added

Comment: Did you remove "static" from the function declaration?

Comment: I am sorry, uploading to the server wasn't working so it did not change the error message.. now the error message is Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Comment: Call $this->connect(); before any database operations

Comment: Once, yes.  According to your error it hasn't been done at all.  Make it the first line of the getUsers() function.  You should also improve your connect() function so that it checks if the connection is already established before creating it and then it wouldn't matter how many times you called connect() in your code.

Comment: I see, could you please provide an example to check the connection if it is established? I am newbie with PDO.

Comment: Did I satisfactorily answer your original question?  If so, please accept the answer and open a new question

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, get a little more familiar with f3 before trying to create this kind of skeleton. The code you have posted seems to indicate that there are a couple key concepts that you can make good use of that you may not be familiar with.

**Use templates** call the template from controller using `echo \Template::instance()->render('templates/controller_index.htm');`

**Use F3 ORM** Though somewhat limited compared to some other ORMs such as Eloquent, the F3 ORM does speed up dealing with the database. read up on it here: http://fatfreeframework.com/databases

```
$user=new DB\SQL\Mapper($db,'users');
$user->load(array('userID=? AND password=?','cheetah','ch1mp')); // load one user
$allusers = $user->find(); // get all users
```

Based on the model code you have, I would say you can get away without using any Models at all, using the Mapper class can take you a long way.

**store configuration in a config file**. This will separate the configuration information from the logic.

```
$f3->config("config.ini");
```

Any value defined there can be accessed like a global

```
[globals]
DEBUG=0
CACHE=true

; Database
db.host=localhost
db.port=3306
db.user=root
db.pass=
db.name=phproject

; Session lifetime
; Also set session.gc_maxlifetime in php.ini
JAR.expire=604800
```

like so...

```
// Connect to database
$f3->set("db.instance", new DB\SQL(
    "mysql:host=" . $f3->get("db.host") . ";port=" . $f3->get("db.port") . ";dbname=" . $f3->get("db.name"),
    $f3->get("db.user"),
    $f3->get("db.pass")
));
```

If you put that code in your index file before you call any controller, you can call your database connection easily. using `$f3->set("db.instance",...)` you create and set the connection

```
// get reference to instance and initialize mapper
$user = new DB\SQL\Mapper($f3->get("db.instance"),'users');

// get all records (same as SELECT * FROM $tablename) and put them inside all_users var
$f3->set('all_users', $user->find());
```

if you then use this information in your template file, you'd do something like this

```
<table>
<repeat group="{{ @all_users }}" value="{{ @user }}">
    <tr>
        <td>{{ @user.attrib1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ @user.attrib2 }}</td>
        <td>{{ @user.attrib3 }}</td>
    </tr>
</repeat>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel for the good example.. I will take a look at it and let you know